# LeetCode Question #22 How to debug recursion problems?

Tags: c++, recursion, depth-first-search, parentheses

[LeetCode 22. Generate Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/)

> Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.
>
> For example, given n = 3, a solution set is:
>
> ```
> [
>   "((()))",
>   "(()())",
>   "(())()",
>   "()(())",
>   "()()()"
> ]
> ```

I am not too sure what is going wrong with my code below. I am using dfs to generate all combinations of well formed parenthesis and I do this by keeping track of the number of left brackets remaining and the number of right brackets remaining. However, the number of remaining brackets are different after I return from a recursion call which causes there to be extra brackets.

```
vector<string> generateParentheses(int n) {
    vector<string> result;
    dfs(result, "", n, n);
    return result;
}

void dfs(vector<string> &result, string s, int num_left, int num_right){
    if(num_left == 0 && num_right == 0){
        result.push_back(s);
    }
    if(num_left > 0){
        dfs(result, s += "(", num_left - 1, num_right);
    }
    if(num_right > 0 && num_right > num_left){
        dfs(result, s += ")", num_left, num_right - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with extra brackets, is that in the first recursive call you make `s+="("`, modifing the string s, but don't modify the variable `num_left`, and when you make the second recursive call, num_left is not the adecuated value

Comment: I still don't quite understand. For example, if my string is "(" in my original call and I have 2 left and 3 right brackets remaining. I then make the first recursive call and in that call my string would be "((" so I have 1 left and 3 brackets remaining. If I backtrack to the original call and then make the second recursive call, I would have in that call the string "()" with 2 left and 2 right. But if I modified it, I would have 1 left and 2 right which would be incorrect? So I guess my guess my question is shouldn't I not modify num_left so that it does not affect the second recursive call?

Comment: Eduardo is saying just change `s += ")"` to `s + ")"`. `+=` permanently modifies `s` in that frame which messes up the right recursive call.

Comment: Oh okay, I misread his reply. Thank you guys very much!